# What is the pattern for testing void functions with NUnit?

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, assert, assertions

I want to add a Test for a void method, and got this far:

```
[Test]
public void TestDuckbilledPlatypusInterface()
{
    var dbPlatypus = IOC.container.Resolve<IDuckbilledPlatypus>();

    dbPlatypus.InsertIntoPoisonousFoot(HttpWebRequest httpwebreq);

    Assert.? <= assert what? or what?
}
```

What can I assert in this case - just that it ran without throwing an exception? If so, what is the received methodology for doing that?

Comment: @TGH's answer is a better idea, but to test that no exception is thrown in NUnit you can use `Assert.That(() => someVoid(), Throws.Nothing)` or `Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => someVoid())`

Comment: Thanks, this works:
 Assert.That(() => DeliveryItem, Throws.Nothing);
(no "()")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing for "no exception thrown" is of some value, but I would try to also test for possible side effects from the void method. (Properties set etc).

If this is a repository method it might actually be more valuable to write an integration test instead where you test that the correct row was inserted into the database.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Preston Guillot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21418/preston-guillot) advised in a comment on your question, you can direct NUnit to assert that an exception is not thrown when your method is called:

[ThrowsNothing Constraint](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/ThrowsNothingConstraint.html):

```cs
var myObj = new MyClass();
Assert.That(() => myObj.VoidMethod(), Throws.Nothing);
```

*or*, via a [classic assertion](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Assert.DoesNotThrow.html):

```cs
Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => myObj.VoidMethod());
```

And, as advised in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24564426/1497596) posted by [@TGH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/336423/tgh), you could in addition check for a change to the state of the object, and/or test for a change to an underlying resource such as a database.

However, in my case, that was not applicable since my `void` method was simply checking whether the object under test could be validated:

```cs
Assert.That(() => myObj.ValidateAndThrow(), Throws.Nothing));
```

(If not valid, the object throws with one or more explanations, which is ultimately returned by a web service as a [400 Bad Request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_client_errors) response.)